# How to extend the checkout Success block?

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, theme

In `module-checkout`, there are 2 `blocks` as below. I am working to show a custom `success page` so **which one we have to override?**
    what is the correct way?

```
Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
and 
Magento\Checkout\Block\Success
```

Is there any option that the `success.phtml` file call from custom module instead of the repective `theme` (`checkout_onepage_success.xml`)?

Answer (score 4):

**Override block**

Create the file `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml` and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Success"/>
</config>
```

Create the file `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Success.php` and add the following:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success {

    public function getOrder() {
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    }

}
```

**Override template**

Create the file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml` and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success" template="Your_Module::checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create the file `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/checkout/success.phtml` and add the following:

```
<?php /** @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Success */ ?>
<div class="checkout-success">
    <?php if ($block->getOrderId()):?>
        <?php if ($block->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
            <p><?php echo __('Your order number is: %1.', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="order-number"><strong>%s</strong></a>', $block->escapeHtml($block->getViewOrderUrl()), $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p><?php echo __('Your order # is: <span>%1</span>.', $block->escapeHtml($block->getOrderId())) ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <!-- BEGIN VENDOR_MODULE CUSTOM -->
        <p><?php echo __('You ordered %1 items.', (int) $block->getOrder()->getTotalQtyOrdered()) ?></p>
        <!-- END VENDOR_MODULE CUSTOM -->

        <p><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We\'ll email you an order confirmation with details and tracking info.') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalInfoHtml() ?>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <a class="action primary continue" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl() ?>"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Continue Shopping') ?></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That's about it, hope I could be of any help.

#### Edit

You probably want to refresh your checkout/success page a lot, so to tackle that problem, go to file `app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.phtml` and change

```
$session->clearQuote();
```

to

```
// $session->clearQuote();
```

This way, your quote won't get cleared when you open the page.

**Updated At :- 13th Sep, 2022**

**Alternative Method (optional)**

we can also override the template as like below one. Note that I used Magento 2.4 version. I doesn't tested with below Magento 2.4 versions.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::checkout/success.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have already checked the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921568/magento-2-get-order-preview-on-success-page

Comment: @KishanPatadia thanks for the very detailed working code also I appreciate the explanation of code in your answer. It is strange that it is not accepted as an answer.